# Automated Excel document creation using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, automation

The managing director at our company wants me to produce an automated monthly document that saves to a certain place on our system so that he doesn't have to manually input all of the data. I have set up so that the document can save to the correct place in the correct format but my knowledge of VBA is not great.

Tackling this from a 1 question at a time point of view I suppose my question would be is it possible to create 1 very long macro that will accomplish many different tasks over several workbooks. For example we have a report that comes from our ERP (Baan) and shoves all of the data into one cell. Is it possible to create a macro that will accomplish formatting text to columns, then copy data from a cell based on a row reference and then take said data and paste it in to a different workbook? Would it then be able to save the workbook all from just running one macro and if so how long will all of that take once the macro is executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I believe this should be do-able, keeping in mind that the file names + location remain the same (otherwise you'll have to edit each month). Create different Subs/Functions and call them in one main macro.

The easiest way is probably to do it step by step. Record macro's and see whether that already helps you out and if not use google & stackoverflow for help! :)

Comment: The file name is fine because it is set to save as follows

ctiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Documents and Settings\username\Desktop\AutoFinance\MonthlyDashboard\" & Format(Date, "YYYYMM") & "DB" & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51

Comment: As such it will save month and year plus "DB" so once a month should be fine

Comment: That's perfect, but I meant the files you use to get the data from ;)

Comment: the files will follow the same format but they will be saved under MMYYTB (trial balance) so each month I will have to update and run the code

Comment: This is another thing that I was concerned about, being automated and very long in terms of 1 macro that it might not have the best error handling and with the managing director not wanting to look over it I am concerned that he could get misinformed and ultimately that's on my head

Comment: It's do-able but it may not be the best solution and the effort will probably be higher than the result you get out of it?

Comment: Adding another point: error testing in vba is piss poor - sou you cound not guarantee it will work in all circumstances.
I really like VBA for small tools - but for a lot of problems its like using a hammer when you have to thread garn through needles

Comment: Christian that did make me chuckle out loud haha. Yeah we are using outdated systems with outdated software and poor IT management

Answer (score 0):

it is entirely possible - but in my Opinion VBA is not well suited to the task. The editor is atrocius at best and it is easy to produce highly specific "spaghetti code". 
File operatione are possible, but are not nice. Error handling is 80s style with lots of goto.
So if you want to build something maintainable, build an external Application using Interop or epplus (.net package for reading /writing to excel documents) or an .net addin for office.

Comment: additionally, you can't pull all data into one cell, it's a excel limitation of numbers of characters in once single cell 

and vba code usually is slow

Comment: I would love to build an application in .net either VB or C# but it turns out that the company will not buy visual studio for me to do this, I am also running a slow system that is old and does not even have the capacity for 2 monitors. So to get the overall idea you say that it is possible but will be extremely time consuming and ineffecient?

Comment: Interesting, with Interop you mean .net's COM Interop I guess? You also have any examples of .net addins for Office?

Comment: At my company I have build Tools with VBA and  vb.net.
The expense for Visual studio is small compared to the endless hours you spend trying to build something worthwile with VBA.

Your answer sums my opinion up - probably you can come up with something working fast, but adding features is a pain.

Comment: Yeah interop is COM Interop, there are exaples of that banging about on here to give you general idea or info

Comment: Are the free C#/VB Express apps not good enough to use for this?

Comment: You should visual studio express, it can be used in companies AND its free.
.net addins for office look great, but I cannot program sam (missmatch between office version and visual studio version) , sorry

Yes com interop was my suggestion.

Comment: I have C# and VB express but the way the company works means that I have no admin rights and as such when I try to run an application that would accomplish such tasks it tells me that I don't have the permissions to make it happen

Comment: Why not ask for permission? Tell them it isn't possible to accomplish their demands without the correct rights? :)

Comment: Because head office of our company is based in the Netherlands and they like to keep everything close to their chest. If we have even the slightest IT problem we have to phone them and get them to fix it remotely

Comment: that's rubbish, but how IT works in a lot of companies :( Is it possible to copy the data to a pc that's not connected to your companies network?

Comment: Suggested and rejected, I have visual studio at home (ultimate edition) that I offered to bring in with my PC and completely make an application etc, however they were not happy that I would not be monitored and that I would not be controlled by head office like everyone else

Comment: Just copy the files you need, mail them to your personal email, run your macro/program on the files and get the results they want? :) That's how I sometimes get around things, using Logmein/Teamviewer you could do it from work too :P It's like saying "Build me a house, but you're not allowed to use stones, wood, mortar, tools and I need it now!"

Comment: You aren't wrong there haha, seems like they want me to write an amazing program and the tools I am allowed are 1 tablet of concrete, 1 hammer and 1 chisel. So we think it's do-able but unmaintainable and over complicated for what it is. Plus working from home would be fine if I wasn't so tired when I got in and needed the weekends to recover

Comment: LogmeIn ;) keep your desktop on and use it at work :D I've had a similar problem and just did it this way, no questions asked when they have the result normally ;)

Comment: I understand the idea of Rep on here but why ask me to avoid extended discussion or move to chat and when I move to chat tell me I do not have enough rep for that...

Comment: Which product of LogMeIn would you suggest? might get it and claim it back from the company as expenses

Comment: I suggest the free version? :P

Comment: will it have the functionality of the paid versions or is it very similar, do you not get much more for your money?